# Two PC's, shared power grid, can this be reasonably done?

Tags: power-supply

I've got quite a data headache.

Motherboard A has partially failed.

I replaced it with board B.  Oops, board B won't play nice with the RAID card.  Oops again, part of the backup of that RAID array failed.

Now, obviously, I can remount the failed board and pull the data off.  The swaps are a royal pain, though, not to mention the downtime during the copy.

Pulling all the drives out and keeping the wires straight would likewise be a royal pain.

By far the easier answer would be to simply set the failed board next to the working machine and plug the card into the old board.  (The wires are long enough to do this.)  The power supply in the machine should be enough to run the second board or it could be run off it's own supply.

What's the best approach here?

Comment: Define "does not play nice?" Not recognized at all, or properly?  Which RAID card? Updated RAID card firmware(if available)?  Updated motherboard BIOS?

Comment: @cybernard Windows sees it but gets an error 10.  Google turns up one person who got past that--but only to be stopped by another error.

Comment: Did you go to the RAID card manufacturers website and get the lastest BIOS and drivers?

Comment: @cybernard I already have the latest drivers.  Flashing the BIOS isn't going to solve it but could trash the array.  I just want to copy the data off.

Comment: What version of Windows xp,vista,7,8,8.1?

Comment: Have you tried moving it to different PCI or PCI-E slots, as IRQ's are shared differently between them?

Comment: http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/261219762884?lpid=82  ATX Y cable the rest of cables are simple for sharing a PSU.  Assuming your PSU has enough watts.

Comment: @cybernard 7/64, fully patched.  I can't find anyone who has solved the compatibility problem, I'm just interested in the data.

Comment: @cybernard So you're saying a splitter like that will let you run two motherboards on one PSU?

Comment: Yes if the watts are high enough say 600w+.

Comment: @cybernard Any idea where they might be found?  I've found the splitter for the 8-pin power connector but I'm having zero luck with the 24-pin.

Comment: The link I previously provided is a link to ebay to someone selling one http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/261219762884?lpid=82